# How to get a position of a drag clone image using jquery

Tags: jquery, position

I want position of a drag clone image after drop it on droppable area.

$("#dhtmlgoodies_xpPane .draggable").draggable({
            start: function(event, ui) {
            var Startpos = $(this).position();
        $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
    },

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
   var Stoppos = $(this).position();
    $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
}
```

});
  but it get only image from menu not the clone image.

Comment: Did you change the `ID` after cloning cos jquery selector using `ID` s only returns the first match

Comment: no. actually I don't know how to do it. can you refer some code?

Comment: `$("#clonething").clone().attr("id","newID").appendTo("#Whereveryouwant");`

Comment: is it added into the  drop section---"$("#working-area").droppable({ here });"

Comment: if have already been using `clone()` in your code add the code to change the `ID` otherwise your problem is not what i think..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949172/jquery-draggable-position-clone